# copy and autorelease local var in block

Tags: objective-c, copy, block, autorelease

Inside a function, I have a local variable that is holding a copy of a date that is a member variable. There's nil protection at the top of the code against _date.

```
if (!_date) return;

NSDate *date = [[_date copy] autorelease];
```

lower in the function date used in a block.

But, inside the block sometimes (rare) date is nil. There are no other calls to release date in the function that does this. Can anyone explain what's happened?

Code sample here:

```
    NSDate *date = [[_date copy] autorelease];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Cache Label Image
    NSDateFormatter *weekday = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    //Name of day label
    UILabel *nameOfDay = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    [weekday setDateFormat: @"EEE"];
    nameOfDay.text = [weekday stringFromDate:date];
    [nameOfDay sizeToFit];

    // Draw it on background thread using ImageContext

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(![date isEqualToDate:_date])
            return;
        .
        .
        .
        .   
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to post more of your code. Context is important here. Show the whole method including the block.

Comment: However you don't need the "nil protection", because nil targeted actions are ignored. So also copy will "return" (truly it won't return anything, because it will never be called) nil.

Comment: I do need the nil protection for this function because it is also doing some sizeToFit work inside the block based on the date string.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `_date` is set to nil before your block is executed. When you put `_date` to block compiler threads it as `self->_date` and keeps strong reference to `self` instead of `_date` when block is copied. Probably you just need to move `NSDate *date = [[_date copy] autorelease];` out of block.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW3) for more info

Comment: This is, what he said: "But, inside the block sometimes (rare) date is nil."